# object not being constraint to bottom anchor of center y anchor

Tags: swift, ipad, constraints, center, nslayoutconstraint

My swift code is trying to constraint a object to the bottom of the center y anchor. When the code is built and run on a iPad. That is not doing it. You can see the what is being displayed in the image below. Clearly the object is not touching the center of the screen. The red marks on the image is what I am looking for.

```
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([





        box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.20),
        box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
        box.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
      box.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

        ])
```

[image]

Comment: Is `box` the orange view? Or the red view?

Comment: the box is the organ view

Comment: Hmm... using your exact code, this is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsCJp.png ... I added the blue "guide lines" to show the horizontal and vertical centers.

Answer (score 0):

in order to use constraints programmatically remember to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false in your object

```
let imageAlert: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        iv.backgroundColor = .white
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "soup")
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //here
        return iv
    }()
```

another common mistake is not adding the components to View

```
func addComponents() {
        self.addSubview(container)
        container.addSubview(quit)
        container.addSubview(imageAlert)
        container.addSubview(alertLabel)
        container.addSubview(alertButtonAccept)
        container.addSubview(alertButtonCancel)

    }
```

also if you're not using a custom View to insert your Object use **self**

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

```
    box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.20),
    box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
    box.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
  box.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)

    ])
```

Comment: (equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.20), is causing compile error.